# html structure of headline and author

Tags: html, semantic-markup

My coworker and I are having a discussion that neither of us can find an answer for anywhere online.

I have a list of article headlines on a homepage and the design mockup has the author above the headline. Right now the markup is:

```
<a href="">
<h3>Headline 1</h3>
<span>Author Name</span>
</a>

<a href="">
<h3>Headline 2</h3>
<span>Author Name</span>
</h3>
```

And then I would use flexbox css order to render the author above the headline. It seems correct to me semantically but is that even needed? Are there any advantages or disadvantages or does it not matter at all what the order is in the markup?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what is the order in markup. When the flexbox allow you to change order of the elements, than it is allowed. What is not allowed is having `h3` inside `a` element.

Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements.

Inline elements can contain only data or other inline elements.

Element `a` is inline element. Element `h3` is block element.

Comment: So it also doesn't have any impact for accessibility users also?

Answer (score 0):

In a list of headlines linked to the corresponding articles, you should not use a heading element for the headline. Each heading element creates a section (with an entry in the document outline), which is not warranted in such a case.

You can use the [`cite` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element) for the author name and/or the headline.

When not using a heading element, whether you use the order author-headline or headline-author shouldn’t matter semantically. Go with what’s more clear for your users.

However, as you don’t have a block-level element anymore (the `h3`), you should introduce some sort of punctuation (e.g., `:`, or `()`) to make clear where the author/headline begins, or you could place the author name outside of the link.

Showcasing a few different options:

```
<!-- 'cite' element only for the headline -->

<cite><a href="">Headline</a></cite> (Author)
Author: <cite><a href="">Headline</a></cite>

<a href=""><cite>Headline</cite> (Author)</a>
<a href="">Author: <cite>Headline</cite></a>

<!-- one 'cite' element for both -->

<cite><a href="">Headline</a> (Author)</cite>
<cite>Author: <a href="">Headline</a></cite>

<cite><a href="">Headline (Author)</a></cite>
<cite><a href="">Author: Headline</a></cite>

<!-- two 'cite' elements -->

<cite><a href="">Headline</a></cite> (<cite>Author</cite>)
<cite>Author</cite>: <cite><a href="">Headline</a></cite>

<a href=""><cite>Headline</cite> (<cite>Author</cite>)</a>
<a href=""><cite>Author</cite>: <cite>Headline</cite></a>
```

---

If you were to keep the `h3`, and you wouldn’t use a sectioning content element (like `article`), the HTML order does matter. The heading element sets the scope for everything that *follows* (until it reaches a higher or same-level heading), so the beginning of the link, and the author name (if using the order author-headline), wouldn’t be part of that heading and its implict section. Instead, they would be part of the previous section (i.e., the author of article 2 would be part of the section for article 1).